# Yii Framework - Having issue to setup "INNER JOIN" for relationship

Tags: yii, inner-join, relationship

I'm facing an issue in fetching data using relationship. Below is the detail:

1. I'm having two tables. First is **item_master** and Second is **inventory** table. Since both are having MANY_MANY relationship, so we are having another table named **inventory_items** with two fields (item_id, inventory_id).
2. Below is the relationship detail in ItemMaster Model:

   ```
   'inventories' => array(
       self::MANY_MANY, 
       'Inventories', 
       'inventory_items(item_id, inventory_id)'
   ),

   'inventoryItems'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'InventoryItems','item_id'),
   ```
3. I need to fetch Items of a particular Inventory only. For this, I'm implementing below filter criteria:

   ```
   $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

   $inventory_condition['condition']="inventoryItems.inventory_id=:inventoryID";
   $inventory_condition['params'] = array(
      ':inventoryID' => $filter['inventory_id']
   );
   $inventory_condition['joinType']='INNER JOIN';

   $criteria->with = array("inventoryItems"=>$inventory_condition);

   $items=new CActiveDataProvider('ItemMaster',array('criteria'=>$criteria));
   ```

Problem:

Above code is returning me all the items with the required inventory. And if an item does not belong to that inventory than still it returns that Item but without inventory. I just need that only those Items should return which belong to a particular inventory.

Comment: Do you use debuger? If yes it would be nice to take a look at generated query. If you don't use it, I advice you to get it here http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dbprofiler/ - it will help you understand what's going on. And to show us query)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `together` option to `true`:

```
$inventory_condition['together']=true;
```

But be careful if you are going to use it with `SQL` `LIMIT`.